# Using jq to parse nested JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have a bash script that defines a function that returns dynamic JSON as a result:

```
# inside bash script
numInstances=getInstances();
```

Where an example of the JSON returned by `getInstances()` is:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "id": 193932,
      "name": "foobaz"
    },
    {
      "id": 28348,
      "name": "fizzbuzz"
    }
  ]
]
```

It's important to note that although the JSON is dynamic, it will always be a nested JSON array of the form:

```
[
  [
     <json list here; this is what I need a count of>
  ]
]
```

How can I pipe `jq` to the output of `getInstances()` so that it will parse the JSON and return the number of instances inside the nested JSON array? For example, in the above output, there are 2 "instances" inside the nested JSON array. So I would want `numInstances` to be set to `2`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.[0]|length
```

would suffice, but is not very robust against a violation of assumptions.

Comment: thanks, so: `numInstances=getInstances() | jq.[0]|length`?

Comment: `numInstances=$(getInstances  | jq '.[0]|length')`